# What are the criteria for using a new memory location when initializing a variable?

Tags: c#, variables, reference, equality

I'm running into some issues when writing a new unit test. My comments in the code example explain my specific issue:

```
KeyboardLayout layout
    = Engine.ParseLayout(Dimensions.Create(300, 300), "FooBar", provider);
var dweeb = layout.Layout.SelectMany(t => t);

//Parsed layout is not a mutant
Assert.IsTrue(!layout.IsMutant);

KeyboardLayout newLayout = StandardKeyboardMutations.MutateKeyboard(layout);

var newb = newLayout.Layout.SelectMany(t => t);

//I don't understand why this test fails. They should be stored in seperate memeory locations and therefore not equal by reference comparison.
//Unless of course saying var x = foo doesn't always provide a fresh memory location for the value of foo.
Assert.AreNotEqual(layout, newLayout);
```

this line `Assert.AreNotEqual(layout, newLayout);` always fails.

I don't know why I've been making this assumption (stated in comments) up until now: Declaring a variable always executes a store procedure to a fresh memory location. (one  not being used by a currently running program).

To be clear, the question is, in c#, does  `var x = foo;`  always use a fresh memory cell? If not, what is the criteria for using one? Or maybe it always stores in x the address of the value? Or have I missed something and I am asking the wrong question entirely to the find what is wrong here?

This is my first "official" unit testing experience, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on `StandardKeyboardMutations`. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Custom class. I'd have to come up with a varied example if you want to look at its' implementation.

Comment: The answer probably lies in its implementation though. Unless you've overridden `KeyboardLayout.Equals` you're getting the `ReferenceEquals` implementation. Which means somehow `StandardKeyboardMutations.MutateKeyboard` is returning a reference to *the same object* as `layout` - probably *not* what you intend.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [Assert.AreSame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aresame.aspx) and not [Assert.AreEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal.aspx).

The `Assert.AreSame()` assertion checks that the arguments reference the same objects (you mentioned "same memory location"), while the `Assert.AreEqual()` (and respectively `AreNotEqual()`), assertion checks for the equality of the underlying objects, ie., it checks that `a.Equals(b)`, which can hold true even if `a` and `b` reference different objects.

Comment: This is good information. However, I used the Assert.AreNotSame(); method and the assertion still failed.  These must be referencing the same object even though my example code leads me to believe otherwise.

Comment: If they are nevertheless the same then it is possible that the `StandardKeyboardMutations` utilises the [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to share the mutations it hands out. It would be best if you could expand the question to include the said implementation or relevant portions of it.

Answer (score 2):

> does `var x = foo`; always use a fresh memory cell?

Yes, `x` is always new peace of memory. However, **it doesn't necessary mean what you think it means.**

> Or maybe it always stores in `x` the address of the `value`?

Yes, if `value` type is a reference type. e.g.

```
var x = new MyClass();
var y = x;
```

both `x` and `y` contain reference (you can think of it as an address) to the same peace of memory, where `MyClass()` instance is actually stored.

For value types it's quite different:

```
var x = new MyStruct();
var y = x;
```

The entire object is copied when assigned to `y`. There is no reference, the object itself is stored in `y`.

Comment: I suspect OP actually needed something else. But good start :) what about optimizations and all sorts of aliasing where 2 variables share memory location, boxing... Simple link to Eric Lipperts blog like [Value types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx) may be enough...

Comment: So would you say that in my example code if both dweeb and newb had reference types on the right hand side of the initialization = that they could be referencing the same thing?

Comment: I don't think so, they refer to LINQ in-memory query definition. The reason why you're getting then as equal is because you're using wrong `Assert` method (as the other answer states).